Author's name repeated for abbreviated work in biblatex philosphy-modern bibliography
I'm using the philosophy-modern citation style in biblatex, and I cite two works by the same author, for one which I use an abbreviation and for the other of which I don't. In the bibliography, it ends up printing the author's name twice, once for the work with an abbreviation, the other for the work without one, while for other authors with multiple works in the bibliography the author's name appears only once. I want the author's name to appear in the bibliography only once for all authors.
Here is the MWE:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,backend=biber,language=auto,
     shorthandintro=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iffieldundef{origyear}
         {}
         {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}%
          \setunit{\addspace}}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \iffieldundef{origyear}
         {}
         {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}%
          \setunit{\addspace}}%
       \printlabeldateextra}}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References},
}
\begin{filecontents}{Bibliography.bib}
@article{sommers1970calculus,
  title={The calculus of terms},
  author={Sommers, Fred},
  journal={Mind},
  volume={79},
  number={313},
  pages={1--39},
  year={1970},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@book{sommers1982logic,
  title={The logic of natural language},
  author={Sommers, Fred},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  year={1982}
}

@misc{lnom,
    author={Leinbiz, Gottfried Wilhelm},
    title = {On the Reality of Accidents},
    translator={Rutherford, Donald},
    year={2015},
    origyear={1688}
}

@book{AriewGarb,
    title = {Philosophical Essays},
    author = {Leibniz, Gottfried Wilhelm},
    editors = {Ariew, Roger, and Garber, Daniel},
    translator = {Ariew, Roger, and Garber, Daniel},
    publisher = {Hacket Publishing Company},
    year = {1989},
    shorthand = {AG},
    label = {AG}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\textcite{sommers1970calculus, sommers1982logic} takes propositional terms to denote sets of states of affairs.

\textcite[e.g.,][p. 2]{lnom}) explicitly calls himself a nominalist.

\footnote{Cf. also the following passage from a letter to Arnauld: “All the predicates of Adam either depend upon other predicates of the same Adam or they do not. Then, setting aside all of those predicates that depend upon the others, we need only gather together all the primitive predicates in order to form Adam’s complete notion …” \parencite[p. 74]{AriewGarb}.}

\singlespacing

\newpage

\printshorthands

\printbibliography
\end{document}

Here's what I get:
Abbreviations list:

And from the bibliography:


I want Leibniz's name to appear only once in the bibliography, like Sommers's name does. How can I achieve that?
Note that some of the material in the preamble is there to make the original date of one of Leibniz's writings appear in the citation of it in the text. I'm not sure if that material is responsible for my present problem, but I've included it in my MWE in case it is.

There is a typo: Leinbiz in lnom vs Leibniz in AriewGarb. (Generally speaking the names need to be exactly the same for biblatex to treat them as such. So middle names, use of initials (G. W. Leibniz vs Gottfried W. Leibniz vs Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz) all need to match up.)

Unrelated: There is one comma too much in each of editors = {Ariew, Roger, and Garber, Daniel}, and translator = {Ariew, Roger, and Garber, Daniel},: The comma before the and or after Ariew, Roger shouldn't be there.
